# Remove columns which match some pattern in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large csv files which have several columns as follows:

| M_15_19_yr_ | M_19_25_yr_ | M_25_35_yr_ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 34 | 12 |
| 09 | 21 | 19 |

I want to remove such columns which start from M_{age1}_{age2}_yr. I tried using:

```
df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.startswith(('M_15_19_yr_','M_19_25_yr_','M_25_35_yr_'))
```

However, I have many such columns. How do I remove all of such columns without explicitly writing down each column's name?

Answer (score 2):

You may instead use `str.contains` along with a regex pattern:

```py
df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.contains(r'^M_\d+_\d+_yr$', regex=True))
```

A more general pattern which includes the new case given in your comment below would be:

```py
df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.contains(r'^\w+_(?:\w+_)*\d+_\d+_yr$', regex=True))
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked for this particular string pattern. However, when I try to adapt it to something else, it stopped working. For example: I want to remove these columns as well:  'Count_hom_Census_Nt_35_44_yr', Count_hom_Census_Nt_45_54_yr' etc, it didn't quite work for these columns. Could you explain a bit, how you replaced a digit by \d and how I can use it for any other similar string pattern as well? Thanks

Comment: Check my updated answer for a more general pattern which includes this new case.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain a bit more? What does "^\w+_(?:\wt_)*" represent?

Answer (score 2):

You may check with `filter`

```
df = df.filter(regex = r'^(?!M_\d+_\d+_yr)')
```